# How do I make an anchored regex match in the middle of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, regex, perl, parsing

I can't find a way to have JavaScript regular expression start matching in the middle of a string, *and* have it bound by '^' (have the start of the regex anchored to my specified starting point).

Perl and Python have what I need (although they are entirely different methodologies from each other).

In Perl I can do:

```
$s = 'foo bar baz';
$r = qr/\Gbar/;
pos($s) = 4;
print 'OK' if $s =~ $r;
```

In Python I can do:

```
s = 'foo bar baz'
r = r'bar'             # r'^bar' also works
if re.match(r, s[4:]): # re.match implies '^'
    print 'OK'
```

In JavaScript (at least in Node.js) I try:

```
s = 'foo bar baz';
r = /^bar/g;
r.lastIndex = 4;
if (r.exec(s))
    console.log('OK');
```

Which doesn't work. If I change the second line to:

```
r = /bar/g;
```

Then it does match, but it could have matched at any position after 4 as well (which I don't want).

Background: I'm working on the JavaScript port of a multi-language parsing framework called Pegex, where every terminal is a regex which is tried at the current parsed position (and anchored to the front of it). Efficiency is a concern. For instance, using a substring copy of the input at my starting point would be about the worst solution.

One solution I can think of is to compare the 'index' value of the match to the lastIndex value I set, to see if it matched at the beginning. This throws away the efficiency of '^' but might not cost so much, as the Pegex regexes are generally small and without bracktracking.

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: So, you want a regex match to start at a particular index in the string without doing a substring first?

Comment: That's a decent approximation.

Comment: You may be after a false efficiency here.  It might be much quicker to just do a manual comparison starting at the desired index and NOT use a regex as regex matches are notoriously slow.  You'd have to test to know for sure.  Or, it might be faster to do the `substring()` and use a simple regex rather than a complicated regex that avoids the `substring()`.

Comment: Except that this entire framework is based off of regular expression matches only. Here is the [Pegex grammar](https://github.com/ingydotnet/pegex-pgx/blob/master/pegex.pgx.yaml) to parse Pegex itself. I have to disagree that regex parsing is slow in dynamic languages (references welcome). I would _guess_ that any simple (non backtracking) regex match, is faster than any two other operations. ie a.match(/^b/) is faster than a.substr(0,1) == 'b'.

Comment: You ought to test before you make assumptions.  In [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-non-regex), the `substr()` version is 8x faster than the regex version in Chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00, ingydotnet: [Not match, but only test](http://jsperf.com/substr-vs-regexp)

Comment: @Bergi - same result in [this modified jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-non-regex) using `.test()`.  In this case, the OP is talking about constructing a dynamic regex so I think you have to count that in the performance test which your jsperf doesn't.  But regardless, even your jsperf with the precomputed regex object shows that the substr version is faster in Chrome (different result in your Opera I guess).  The point here is you can't assume.  If you want fast, you have to test.  Constructing and using a regex is NOT a fast operation if there is a reasonable non-regex alternative.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think his case would be comparable to [these tests](http://jsperf.com/compute-regex-vs-substr)

Comment: Incidentally, the Python `:` slice operator creates a substring copy, as opposed to indexing to the same string. Dunno about the efficiency of the slice-copy versus the `^.{4}` regex approach, which would work in Python also.

Answer (score 3):

What about matching "^.{4}actualre" ?

Comment: Now that's a great idea. I'll follow up with a general solution based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the number of characters to where you want to start matching is a very good general solution to this problem (imho).

```
s = 'foo bar baz';                                                          
r = 'bar';                                                                  
p = 4;                                                                      
r = new RegExp('^[\\s\\S]{' + p + '}' + r);                 
if (r.exec(s))                                                              
    console.log('OK');
```

I'll have to test how this performs on large data, but I imagine it could be quite good depending on the regex implementation. For instance if the implementation was aware that [\s\S] was the common way of asking for any char (including newline) in JS, then it could simply index forward in one go.

Any other great ideas? :)

Comment: I came with that idea as well, but I don't think it does perform better than substring operations - regex constructors are costly. BTW, you still can have `r` beeing a literal if you want